# ruby - не принимает Mechanize

Tags: ruby, web-scraping

Всем привет. Учу Руби, тестю Mechanize, застрял на таком вот простом коде:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri' #возможно, эта строчка не нужна
require 'mechanize'

my_url = "https://somepage.com"

mechanize = Mechanize.new

mechanize.get(my_url)

puts mechanize.title
```

Выполнение спотыкается об строчку require 'mechanize'
Пример текста ошибок:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    8: from task1.rb:4:in `<main>'
    7: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
    6: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    5: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.6/lib/mechanize.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:122:in `require'
    2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:122:in `require'
    1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/net-http-persistent-3.0.0/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:190:in `<top (required)>'
```

C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/net-http-persistent-3.0.0/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:205:in `': uninitialized constant Process::RLIMIT_NOFILE (NameError)

Ошибку выдает и в онлайн-компиляторе, так что наверное дело не в компе...

- Пробовал переустановить гем (gem install mechanize)
- подумал, может дело в зависимостях(DEPENDENCIES), потыкал разные гемы со страницы https://rubygems.org/gems/mechanize/versions/2.7.5
- подумал, может ему нужно подключить еще чего, добавил рекуайры "open-uri" и (а вдруг бы?) "nokogiri"
- перезапускал редактор (VS Code)
- перезапустил комп

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема, видимо, в несовместимости не самой последней версии Руби (2.5.3) с последней версией Mechanize (2.7.6). Удалив Механайз, установил более старую версию (на глаз тыкнул 2.5.1), все запустилось. Правда, надо было слегка подправить код:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'
require 'mechanize'

my_url = "https://somepage.com"

mech = Mechanize.new

_page = mech.get(my_url)

puts _page.title
```